# How to loop this question until its answer is right

Tags: python

How do I make it loop again if they say "no" in answer to "Do you want to play again", such that if they say "no" it'll keep on looping back to that question until they say "yes"?

```py
import random

def main(): 
    n = random.randint(3,10)
    guess = int(input(" So "+ name +" guess a number from 3 to 10: "))
    while n != "guess":
        print
        
        if guess < n:
            print("Sorry "+ name +" but, that guess is low")
            guess = int(input("Guess a number from 3 to 10: "))
            
        elif guess > n:
            print("Come on "+ name +" that guess is high")
            guess = int(input("Guess a number from 3 to 10: "))
            
        else:
            print("Congratulations "+ name+" you guessed it!")
            break
    
    restart = input("Do you want to play again: ").lower()
    if restart==("yes"):
        main()

    elif restart ==("no"):
       print("Are you sure about that?")
       restart = input("Do you want to play again: ").lower()
       main()
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```python
while True:
    restart = input("Do you want to play again: ").lower()
    if restart == "yes":
        break
    elif restart == "no":
        print("Are you sure about that?")
main()
```